# screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable

Tags: amd-graphics, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I recently installed a AMDGPU pro driver on my ubuntu 16.04 because of `ring stalled` recurrent freezes. Since then the freezes do not occur anymore. However I tried to run `mendeleydesktop` and doing so I get: 
`screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable`

My graphic card is: 
`03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde GL [FirePro W4100]`

Also it's important to note that `glxinfo` returns: `name of display: :0.0
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig`

I suspect a tuning problem associated to the AMD driver but I can't figure it out and some help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I tried to run `radeon.modeset=0` but it didn't change anything